# Parse "div" which have no name or id , only class atrribute , with htmlClener in android

Tags: android, parsing, htmlcleaner

I am trying to parse the HTML webpage which have the div elements with the only class attribute.
I need to extract information from it.
It is multiple div element with so i need to traverse through DOM. But I can't identify the div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Switch to [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), It's really awesome!

In my opinion you should use [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup). It is Java HTML parser. Its feature is listed below.

- Ability to fetch web pages from network
- Very simple and straightforward API
- CSS selector to tagert HTML element(s).

For example you want to get a DIV elements with class `foo`

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://website.com/").get();
Elements divs = doc.select("div.foo");
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but Its taking too much time. can you describe?

Comment: @Hussainsoni [This article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/) will get you started. Have a look!

Answer (score 0):

If you use HtmlCleaner's JDom serializer, you can then use an XPath expression to locate the div.